# character manipulation in file cmd

Tags: text, cmd

this is file.txt

```
hello
hai
```

So i wanna create a program that will read this file. and then replace every ALPHABET with the succeeding one. keeping all numbers and other symbols intact.

so the file.txt would become

```
ifmmp
ibj
```

current have tried reading every \n and then reading every character in the line, but echoing them would result in it being in different lines
ie

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('^<%path% findstr /n "^"') do (
set "line=%%i"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line=!line:*:=!"
set "num=-1"
:loop
set /a num=num+1
call set "name2=%%line:~%num%,1%%"
if defined name2 (
rem set /a name2+=1 this statement wont work
    echo %name2%
goto :loop )
```

)

but then the output i get is

```
echo is off
e
l
l
o
```

any ideas?

Comment: The `set /a` command does only work with numbers, I have an answer for alfas, not numbers, signs and so on. If you are intrestet, edit your question first.

Comment: yes intereseted, i figured the set /a doesnt work but i didnt know what did.

Comment: look [here](http://pastebin.com/642k5SMv) for the new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set /a` command does only work with numbers, you can try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "alfa=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"
set "test=hello hai"

set /a num=0
:loop
call set "char=%%test:~%num%,1%%"
if not defined char goto:eof
call set "alf1=%%alfa:*%char%=%%"
if "%char%" neq " " echo %alf1:~0,1%
set /a num+=1
goto:loop
```

..output is:

```
i
f
m
m
p
i
b
j
```

Comment: any way to make it in the same line as in original?

Comment: Yes, don't echo it, put it on a line and echo it after parsing.

Comment: @Nisham Mohammed - Please put your code at pastebin, I can't read it in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ROT13 batch file - what you are describing is a ROT1 translation.  Maybe this will work for you as it is, or give you ideas and you can modify it.

```
@echo off
:: by aacini
:: program works as a filter, that is, it read lines from keyboard (stdin) and send output to screen (stdout). "type filetext.txt|rot13.bat" or "rot13.bat < filetext.txt"
:: with d benham update

@echo off
:: simple rot-13 conversion filter program
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set lower=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
set upper=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
for /l %%a in (0,1,25) do (
  set /a "rot13=(%%a+13)%%26"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for %%b in (!rot13!) do for /f "tokens=1-4" %%A in (
    "!lower:~%%a,1! !lower:~%%b,1! !upper:~%%a,1! !upper:~%%b,1!"
  ) do (
    endlocal
    set "lower%%A=%%B"
    set "upper%%C=%%D"
  )
)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /n "^"') do (
  set "line=%%a"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "line=!line:*:=!"
  set output=
  if defined line (
    set /a len=0
    for /l %%b in (12,-1,0) do (
      set /a "len|=1<<%%b"
      for %%c in (!len!) do if "!line:~%%c,1!" equ "" set /a "len&=~1<<%%b"
    )
    for /l %%b in (0,1,!len!) do (
      set "char=!line:~%%b,1!"
      if defined lower!char! for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%c in ("!char!") do (
        if "!lower:%%c=%%c!" neq "!lower!" (
          set "char=!upper%%c!"
        ) else set "char=!lower%%c!"
      )
      set "output=!output!!char!"
    )
  )
  echo(!output!
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: confused on how to edit it. cou;d you add comments in it to explain it?